# CakePHP pagination to page 10 or more redirected to not found url

Tags: cakephp, redirect, pagination, cakephp-1.3

My application on the local host is set to sub document root directory i.e localhost/mysite. However, I use pagination for several models. There is a strange issue I have found after upgrading to [cakephp-1.3](/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.3) that is, pagination works fine with pages less than page 10 for example:
`http://localhost/mysite/searches/page:2` works fine
but `http://localhost/mysite/searches/page:10` is redirected to `http://localhost/searches` This issue is found in other models.

Of course, routes should not cause this, because it is repeated problem with other models and cations.

The following is the controller seraches:

```
class SearchesController extends AppController {
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Paginator');
    var $components = array('Session', 'Auth');
    function beforeFilter() {
parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('top', 'index');
}
public function beforeRender() {
parent::beforeRender();

}

function index(){
  $this->Search->recursive = 0;
  $this->paginate = array('order' => array('times' => 'DESC'));
        $this->set('searches', $this->paginate());  
}
```

Also a working example of my website pagination is [here](http://quran.2index.net/searches/page:9) from that link try to access page 10, it will redirect you to the index of the searches controller!

Comment: Have you done some debugging? Does is actually reach the `index` action? Does it actually hit the app at all? What does your '.htaccess' rules look like? And even tough you think it's not related to routes, what do your routes look like? CakePHP for sure won't issue a `301` redirect on its own.

Comment: @ndm Exactly you are right. it is .htaccess I had set a rule the redirect anything/page:1 to be anything/ however, the rule was applied to 10, 11,... 19 and 100...199 etc I fixed it and everything works fine. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

it's alway happen when there are 2 paginators in the same page.

If 1st paginator has 10 pages, and another one has more than 10 pages.

It will error from pages 11 and upper.